# Snap .clear clears also Defs

Tags: snap.svg

I am using snap.svg, but i am not getting the supposed results.

```
        var allLayer = s.selectAll('#svg2 > g');
        allLayer.forEach(function(elem, i) {
            elem.toDefs();
        });
        s.clear();
```

s.clear also clears the defs. not like it is mentioned in the docs.
[snap.svg documentation](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.clear)

Comment: If its not working as per the doc, I'd be tempted to raise an issue on github https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg

Comment: Can somebody review this? before i got it posted as an issue?